# Normal map does not export into .dae file. Does Collada not support normal maps?

Tags: maya, normal-mapping, collada

Every time I try to use DAE FBX export in Autodesk Maya and export a .dae file the normal map doesn't export with it? Does Collada not support normal maps?

Comment: In blender, I had to 'bake' the normal map out into an image - It could sometimes be a long process, and definitely wasn't automatically generated when I exported the model. I'm sure this process is similar in maya. A quick google gave me this: http://cgterminal.com/2013/09/23/maya-baking-normal-maps-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can think off is that it's not correct in the .dae.

Open the .dae file in a text editor. Search for:

```
<bump>
```

If it's just called `<bump>`, change it to:

```
<bump bumptype="NORMALMAP">
```

Then, below your material type, and above `</technique>`, paste the following and replace with your normal texture name. In context, it should look like this:

```
</phong>
<extra>
  <technique profile="FCOLLADA">
    <bump bumptype="NORMALMAP">
      <texture texture="example_Normal_jpg-sampler" texcoord="UVMap"/>
    </bump>
  </technique>
</extra>
</technique>
```